# How to perform text classification on unlabelled test data?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, svm, text-mining

I am using TF-IDF to perform feature extraction and then passing the sparse matrix to perform training along with text data which is also transformed to sparse matrix. I understand that the input to classifier for training and testing requires text and labels both. Since both training and testing dataset are labelled, which is the ususal method to perform classification to later check using statistical measures how good the model is.

But if we want to classify unlabelled test data, how can we do so in the same manner? E.g., applying TF-IDF and then using a classifier.

Any guidance is appreciated please.

Comment: You might want to look at latent topic analysis algorithms (LDA, LSA, LSI, etc.). They are a class of unsupervised clustering algorithms. The issue is that you do not explicitly state a target in these. Plus, boundaries between classes are not always (or most often) not distinct.

Comment: A quick way is to do forward propagation with your trained weights, e.g., get the logits, and then apply softmax to the logits. Then get the max of that, and that will then correspond to one of your classes.